# New mail notifications for Outlook additional mailboxes

Tags: windows-vista, microsoft-outlook-2007

I use multiple mailboxes in Outlook.

My primary mailbox is ap@mywork.dk

But I also have additional mailboxes e.g. reception@mywork.dk, support@mywork.dk

Now whenever I get a mail in my inbox, ap@mywork.dk, I get a notification - a small blue box with the topic and name of sender is displayed on the lower right corner of my monitor for a few seconds.

Is it possible to apply that form of alert to other mailboxes, like reception@mywork.dk?

I want to make clear though, I can't just autoforward the mails from that inbox to my own. it would create more problems than solutions to mix the inboxes like that.

I've attempted to look through the possible settings on the inbox 'reception@mywork.dk' can't seem to find anywhere to turn on notifications or alerts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [this page](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/outlook/thread/06bbfb92-1163-438f-9582-e3ad14ec2ceb) this possibility is available in Outlook 2010:

> Are either the primary or secondary Exchange accounts running in Cached Exchange Mode? **If the second account is in Cached Mode, then you will see the new email notifications.**

Unfortunately this option does not exist in Outlook 2007. [Here is a blog post](http://techniclee.wordpress.com/2010/12/16/new-mail-notification-for-an-additional-mailbox/) that suggests a workaround using VBA:

> It doesn’t look or behave the same as the built-in notification, but it is functional. The solution is to use a bit of scripting to monitor the additional mailbox’s inbox, watch for new items, and display a pop-up dialog-box when it detects one. The dialog-box is a standard Windows’ dialog, not the slick-looking notification that Outlook uses. The dialog doesn’t fade in and out, nor does it offer the ability to open or delete the message as Outlook’s notification dialog does. It will steal focus and you have to click a button to make it go away.

Comment: well looks like its gonna have to wait untill we upgrade our outlook

Comment: Looks like you can trigger a balloon tooltip from vba, which might be a little less intrusive http://www.vbaexpress.com/forum/showthread.php?34563-Show-system-tray-balloon-tooltip-in-VBA

Answer (score 3):

You can accomplish this by setting up a rule in the relevant mailbox:

1. In the `Rules and Alerts` dialog, click `New Rule...`
2. Select `Apply rule on messages I receive` then click `Next`:

   [image]
3. Select the condition `sent to people or public group`, selecting the group mailbox identifier, then click `Next`:

   [image]
4. Select the action `display a Desktop Alert`:

   [image]
5. Click `Finish`. Accept the prompt that states this will be run on the client only.

Comment: Have you tested this? I just tried your solution with Outlook 2010 and it doesn't work.

Comment: Ditto. Unable to reproduce.