# How to get a Display Alert based on Category color

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2013

I use multiple mailboxes in Outlook.

My primary mailbox is me@example.com

But I also have 1 additional mailbox e.g. shared@example.com

Now whenever I get a mail in my inbox, me@example.com, I get a notification - a small blue box with the topic and name of sender is displayed on the lower right corner of my monitor for a few seconds.

My boss uses categories (colors) to assign items in the Shared Mailbox. My color is Green. Is it possible to get a popup alert whenever something is categorized as "Green". The message maybe "read"

I want to make clear though, I can't just autoforward the mails from that inbox to my own. it would create more problems than solutions to mix the inboxes like that.

I saw this

[New mail notifications for Outlook additional mailboxes](https://superuser.com/questions/482806/new-mail-notifications-for-outlook-additional-mailboxes)

but I need it to apply to any and all mail (read or unread) that changes the "Category" color

Answer (score 0):

No way without building quite complex VBA solution. You will need to create a Form and then color it an show it modeless in a VBA macro. You'll also need to run this macro from Outlook rule instead of "Show Desktop Alert" action.

Comment: Why would this be complex? My rules work. I just need a macro or something to run my rule every 5 minutes